# Insert text before first instance of tags

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a bunch of documents that I'm trying to style with xslt and I have some code like this:

```
<tag1>Something</tag1>
<tag2>Something else</tag2>
<tag3>...</tag3>
```

But in some documents there may only be:

```
<tag2>Something else</tag2>
<tag3>...</tag3>
```

When I render the document I want to add a "`<h2>Heading</h2>`" before either tag1, tag2 or tag3 (which ever comes first). Is this possible?

Comment: it would be easier if you could reliably find the containing element

Comment: You're right it would be, but I'm working with data supplied by someone else and there's no containing element for these tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I found that worked for me:

```
<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'tag')][1]" priority="1">
  <h2>Heading</h2>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[starts-with(name(), 'tag')]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/tag1" mode="display">
  <p>First tag:
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/tag2" mode="display">
  <p>Second tag:
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="root/tag3" mode="display">
  <p>Third tag:
  <xsl:apply-templates />
  </p>
</xsl:template>
```

A bit unorthodox, but it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

**As simple as this (no conditional instructions, no `xsl:element`, no `starts-with()` , no `preceding-sibling::` axis, no modes, only one template overriding the standard identity rule):**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*[self::tag1 or self::tag2 or self::tag3][1]">
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document** (the provided fragment wrapped into a single top element to be made a well-formed XML document):

```
<t>
    <tag1>Something</tag1>
    <tag2>Something else</tag2>
    <tag3>...</tag3>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<t>
   <h2>Heading</h2>
   <tag1>Something</tag1>
   <tag2>Something else</tag2>
   <tag3>...</tag3>
</t>
```

**Do note**:

In case there are many element names (not necessarily starting with the same string, it would be shorter and practical to re0write the match pattern of the last template like this:

```
 <xsl:template match=
  "*[contains('|tag1|tag2|tag3|', concat('|',name(),'|'))][1]">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:if test="count(./preceding-sibling::*)=0"><h2>Heading</h2></xsl:if>
```

This means that the current node is preceded in the document by 0 sibling elements (i.e. is the first element of its parent). But as commented: locating the parent element and prepending the H2 to its output would yield much better performance.

There always is a containing tag, in worst case it's the document-element itself.

Comment: Unfortunately the XML I posted is only a snippet, there is code before and after this.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach:

```
<xsl:template match="*[tag1|tag2|tag3]">
<xsl:element name="{name()}">
<h2>Heading</h2>
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tag1|tag2|tag3">
<xsl:element name="{name()}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This XSLT 1.0 style-sheet...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="ident">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[self::tag1|self::tag2|self::tag3]
                      [not(preceding-sibling::tag1|
                           preceding-sibling::tag2|
                           preceding-sibling::tag3)]">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <xsl:call-template name="ident" />
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...or equivalently this XSLT 2.0 one...**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[self::tag1|self::tag2|self::tag3]
                      [not(preceding-sibling::tag1|
                           preceding-sibling::tag2|
                           preceding-sibling::tag3)]">
  <h2>Heading</h2>
  <xsl:next-match />
</xsl:template>      
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...will transform this input document..**

```
<t>
  <branch1>
    <something-before/>
    <tag1>Something</tag1>
    <tag2>Something else</tag2>
    <tag3>tag3 content</tag3>
    <something-after/>
  </branch1>
  <branch2>
    <something-before/>
    <tag3>tag3 content</tag3>
    <tag2>Something else</tag2>
    <something-after/>
  </branch2>
</t>
```

**...into...**

```
<t>
  <branch1>
    <something-before />
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <tag1>Something</tag1>
    <tag2>Something else</tag2>
    <tag3>tag3 content</tag3>
    <something-after />
  </branch1>
  <branch2>
    <something-before />
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <tag3>tag3 content</tag3>
    <tag2>Something else</tag2>
    <something-after />
  </branch2>
</t>
```